# nginx configure pgadmin in location

Tags: nginx, pgadmin, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

Help me please to write config.
It works, but when i go to location http://my.server.ru/pgadmin/ , it redirects to / to login, and there is no location name in /.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name my.server.ru;
    error_log  /home/user/error.log error;
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/django_app.sock;
    }
    location /pgadmin {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050/;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5050 http://$host/pgadmin/;

        }

    location /static/ {
         root    /home/user/django_app;
     expires 365d;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/user/django_app;
     expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}


}
```

I don't understand what to do with it. Where must be rewrite?

UPD:
output of curl

```
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.server.ru (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET /pgadmin/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.server.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://my.server.ru/pgadmin/
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host my.server.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://my.server.ru/pgadmin/'
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.server.ru (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=xxxxxx
*  start date: Jul 31 11:42:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 29 11:42:00 2017 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my.server.ru" matched cert's "my.server.ru"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /pgadmin/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.server.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:51:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 236
< Location: http://my.server.ru/login?next=%2F
< Set-Cookie: pga4_session="c8e21d09-5d31-42e3-a4d5-a3ed87873a69!6KcWbhziK2zypWCzKTRyFLUdszI="; Expires=Thu, 31-Aug-2017 15:51:49 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #1 to host my.server.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://my.server.ru/login?next=%2F'
* Found bundle for host my.server.ru: 0x55568d6af270 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host my.server.ru
* Connected to my.server.ru (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.server.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://my.server.ru/login?next=%2F
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host my.server.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://my.server.ru/login?next=%2F'
* Found bundle for host my.server.ru: 0x55568d6affb0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host my.server.ru
* Connected to my.server.ru (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#1)
> GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.server.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:51:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 79
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #1 to host my.server.ru left intact
```

## Not Found

The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

We see redirect here to /

Comment: Change `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5050 http://$host/pgadmin/;` to `proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5050/ http://$host/pgadmin/;`. Also post output of `curl -vL http://my.server.ru/pgadmin/`

Comment: Posted chenges to config. Done, but I got redirect to root page.

Comment: Okie, seems you have more config and the config you posted is just part of it. Your problem is that the block you are defining is in listen 80 but there is a additional block of redirect to https and the https block doesn't have `/pgadmin`. So you get a https redirect and then `/pgadmin` is not there so you get a `login` redirect

Comment: no I just added proxy_redirect http https; to my config. Its bag I think I foun logout redirect thread. I think th bestway is to do subdomain in this situation?  http://www.postgresql-archive.org/PATCH-To-fix-the-logout-redirects-to-pgAdmin4-td5922476.html

Comment: Not sure, see if that works for you

Comment: yes, there was http>https forse redirect. I found a great soulution - run thrue ssh tunnel, its wotks great and doesn't break security issues.

Answer (score 9):

I ended up with the following configuration:

```
location /pgadmin {
    proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80;
    proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin;
}
```

The most important here is `X-Script-Name`, specifying the path prefix used to build hyperlinks on frontend. The `proxy_redirect` directive is also needed to fix mixed content warnings in browser.

Comment: After countless hours I spent on Nginx reverse proxy this works fine for me too...

Answer (score 0):

Use below Nginx config to create a reverse proxy for PGAdmin

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

location /service/pg/ {
    rewrite ^(.+)/service/pg/(.*)$ $1/$2;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7003/; 
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:7003/ https://$host/service/pg/;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter "/service/pg" "";
    sub_filter '"/static/' '"/service/pg/static/';
    sub_filter "'/static/" "'/service/pg/static/";
    sub_filter '="/login' '="/service/pg/login';
    sub_filter '/browser/' '/service/pg/browser/';
    sub_filter '/tools/' '/service/pg/tools/';
    sub_filter '/settings/' '/service/pg/settings/';
    sub_filter '/misc/' '/service/pg/misc/';
    sub_filter '/preferences/' '/service/pg/preferences/';
    sub_filter '/dashboard/' '/service/pg/dashboard/';
    sub_filter '/user_management/' '/service/pg/user_management/';
    sub_filter '/favicon.ico' '/service/pg/favicon.ico';
    sub_filter '/datagrid/' '/service/pg/datagrid/';
    sub_filter '/sqleditor/' '/service/pg/sqleditor/';
    sub_filter_types "*";
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_last_modified off;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found another good way - run thrue ssh tunnel. Hope it'll helps someone.